# Is there a verbose mode available in Flurry?

Tags: iphone, flurry, verbose

Given that it apparently takes hours for a Flurry "event" to make it to appear on their web server, debugging is kind of slow.  It would be most advantageous if there were some sort of "verbose" mode that would cause Flurry events to be logged to the iPhone debugger console, but I don't see any option for that in the (very limited) Flurry documentation.

Does anyone know if there is some sort of hidden option to enable verbose output?  (And, if so, how to access it?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `[FlurryAPI setDebugLogEnabled:YES];`? (it's exposed in Flurry header file with a bunch of other methods).

**Update for 2016 and later:** it's been 5+ years since I've used Flurry and my answer is not relevant at best. I'd recommend consulting Flurry's documentation.

Comment: Thanks!  That's not mentioned in the "documentation", and I apparently missed it when I initially scanned the .h.

Comment: BTW, do you happen to know what "setShowErrorInLogEnabled" does?  I can guess that it causes any Error event to be logged to console, but that's only a guess.

Comment: its late 2016..and i m struggling to find documentation on log level for flurry..can anyone pls let me know what differences these log levels have - verbose, etc.